# How does the enzyme Dicer function in the RISC complex?

Tags: gene-regulation

I know that the RISC (RNA-induced silencing complex) is one of the primary complexes involved in gene regulation through RNAi.  What I want to know is, what role exactly does Dicer play in this complex?

Answer (score 1):

Dicer is an endo-ribonuclease belonging to the RNAse-III class. Dicer is not a part of the RISC. It however helps in the formation of RISC by cleaving dsRNA or the stem of hairpin RNA on two ends which liberates a small dsRNA product. Then one of the strands is loaded into the RISC.

There are several reviews on this topic and there is a video as well which you can find on youtube.